# How can I find out how many times a specific term has been searched on Google?

Tags: google, search, google-search

Is this information possible to get? If not is there any other source of information that can provide this?

Comment: @stevec I am pretty sure Google keeps the exact, absolute search numbers private. I am not aware of any place they show that to anybody. In limited cases where you're already ranking, it could be useful to look at search impressions on Google Search Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also [Google Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/select/KeywordToolExternal) is a nice reference.

Comment: This tool is no longer available.

Answer (score 3):

#### Step 1: Sign in to Google Ads

#### Step 2: Click on 'Tools & Settings'

[image]

#### Step 3: Click on 'Keyword Planner'

[image]

#### Step 4: Click on the box 'Discover New Keywords'

[image]

#### Step 5: Enter a term and click 'Get Results'

[image]

#### Step 6: View results

[image]

Comment: Presumably "10K - 100K" avg/month still does not satisfy your requirement for an "absolute number"?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but I suppose it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Google Trends?

edit:

Adwords Keywords? [Keywords](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__c=1000000000&__u=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS#search.none)

@Dave beat me to it.